# jqGrid editForm problem

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, editing

I have simply jqgrid definitions like this:

```
jQuery("#C2").jqGrid({
                 url: '/Customers.mvc/GetGridData/',
                 datatype: 'json',
                 autowidth: 'true',
                 mtype: 'GET',
                 colNames: ['Nazwa', 'Symbol', 'Status', 'Miasto', 'Ulica', 'Budynek', 'Mieszkanie', 'Koda pocztowy', 'Domena', ' '],

                 colModel: [
                            { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', align: 'left', editable: 'true', edittype: 'text' },
                            { name: 'Symbol', index: 'Symbol', align: 'left', editable: 'true', edittype: 'text' },
                            { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', align: 'left', editable: 'true', edittype: 'text' },
                            { name: 'City', index: 'City', align: 'left', editable: 'true', edittype: 'text' },
                            { name: 'Street', index: 'Street', align: 'left', editable: 'true', edittype: 'text' },
                            { name: 'Building', index: 'Building', align: 'left', editable: 'true', edittype: 'text' },
                            { name: 'Flat', index: 'Flat', align: 'left', editable: 'true', edittype: 'text'},
                            { name: 'PostalCode', index: 'PostalCode', align: 'left', editable: 'true', edittype: 'text' },
                            { name: 'Domain', index: 'Domain', align: 'left', editable: 'true', edittype: 'text'},
                            { name: 'ExtId', index: 'ExtId', align: 'left', editable: 'true', edittype: 'text'}, 
                             ],
                 pager: jQuery('#C2_p'),
                 rowNum: 30,
                 rowList: [20, 30, 50],
                 sortname: 'Name',
                 sortorder: 'Asc',
                 viewrecords: 'true',
                 width: '80%',
                 height: '100%',
                 editurl: '/Customers.mvc/SaveCustomer/',
                 postData: { gridId: 'Customers' },
                 caption: 'Klienci2'
             }).navGrid('#C2_p', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: false },
             {},//Options for the Edit Dialog
             {},//Options for the Add Dialog
             {}//Options for D

             );

         });
```

And when i call edit/add form it's appears without text edit inputs. I'm using jquery 1.3.2 and jqgrid 3.6.4

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found it :).
I change
editable: 'true'
to 
editable: true
and now it works...